# Algorithm for Wrapping Problem

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

Assume we have n items with each having a different length and m wrappers each has a different length. The cost of every wrapper is proportional to its length. An item can be covered with one or more wrappers but the wrappers can not be divided. What is the algorithm to wrap the item in the cheapest possible way (least cost of the wrappers)? I know this problem is a NP-hard or NP-complete problem. But can not find exactly which problem it can be mapped into.

What should be the approximation scheme for this problem?

Comment: You talk about approximation schemes but do not define which measure you wish to optimize.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the questions. Want to minimize the cost of the wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I'll consider the case in which items and wrappers are allowed to have the same length. What follows extends to your case by dealing with small enough perturbations of the lengths.

It is strongly NP-hard to even decide whether the problem admits a feasible solution.
Indeed, you can reduce from an instance of 3-partition in which you have $3n$ positive integers $x_1, x_2, \dots$ strictly between $\frac{1}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$ and $\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$.
In order to do that, you can consider an instance with $m=3n$ wrappers of lengths $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $n$ items of length $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$.

This means that the approximation ratio is unbounded. Indeed, the cost of a yes-instance is upper bounded by $\sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$, while a costly solution can be forced to exist by adding $n$ additional wrappers of length $L \sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$ for some large enough $L$.

Then, assuming $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, any polynomial-time algorithm that provides an approximation ratio smaller than $\frac{L \sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i} = L$ could be used to solve the decision version of your problem (and hence 3-partition) in polynomial time.

Comment: any relevant paper or book link?  What is the exact name  of the problem?

Comment: The problem I'm reducing from is called [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem). See also the [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem#Variants) section.